# Where can I find all of the out of the ordinary biomes, like sky, hell, and mesa?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was looking on the Minecraft wiki and I saw that it doesn't tell you were to find the specific biomes. It tells you what they are and what is in them but not where to find them. On average would they be? Like near the ocean, next to a forest biome, etc.

Comment: Each world is randomly generated, so it's impossible to tell where each of the biomes are generated in your particular world.

Comment: @MBraedley with the exception of the nether always being hell biome.

Comment: And The End always being Sky Biome, but both of those link to a place that tells more.

Comment: but if they were in the generated world where on average would they be, like near the ocean, next to a forest biome ect.

Comment: completely randomly. It's litterally impossible to say. Ocean is just a biome like any other.

Comment: @Arperum I don't think that was bob@bob.bob's point. I think by that comment he's asking about what biomes occur next to each other (like beach next to ocean, jungle doesn't occur next to ice plains, etc...)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The biomes in Minecraft are generated via a random seed. If you want to know exactly where everything is, you'd have to first know the given seed. For example, there is a birch forest at coordinates 0, 0 using the seed `JAMESOFDAPEACH`, but on any other seed there might not be a birch forest there.

In order to use a seed, click on "More World Options" when creating a new world and copy/paste the seed into the box. You can try this out:

Put in `JAMESOFDAPEACH` in there with cheats enabled and then do /tp @p 0 150 0, you'll be in a birch forest. But if you generate another world with a slightly different seed, there won't be (most likely).

Use a site like [this one](http://www.minecraftseeds.info/) to view some user-submitted seeds and descriptions.

There are some basic rules to the "random" generation though: Next to an ocean there are beaches, and biomes with cold climates won't occur next to a warm climate as of 1.7. (jungles and deserts shouldn't be found next to taiga and ice plains). The hell biome is only accessible in the Nether, and I believe the sky biome was intended for the [Sky Dimension](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sky_Dimension) but never implemented - instead the Sky biome is for the End.